# Android studio error in the code

Tags: android

Hey guys i am working on a sample projent on android studio and i am a beginner in  this. I am getting an error please help with this.

Error

Error:(54, 68) error: constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: FirebaseRecyclerOptions
found: Class,int,Class,DatabaseReference
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
where T,VH are type-variables:
T extends Object declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
VH extends ViewHolder declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Error:(62, 50) error: cannot find symbol method getContent()

The main code is below

MainActivity()

```
package com.hof_university.chethan.chatmessenger;

import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editMessage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private RecyclerView mMessageList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMessageE);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Messages");
        mMessageList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.messageRec);
        mMessageList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mMessageList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    }

    public void sendButtonClicked(View view){
        final String messageValue = editMessage.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(messageValue)){
            final DatabaseReference newPost = mDatabase.push();
            newPost.child("content").setValue(messageValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Message,MessageViewHolder> FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>(
                Messages.class,
                R.layout.singlemessagelayout,
                MessageViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Message model) {
                      viewHolder.setContent(model.getContent());
            }

            @Override
            public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }
        };
        mMessageList.setAdapter(FBRA);
    }

    public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setContent(String content){
            TextView message_content = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.messageText);
            message_content.setText(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use  [FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/index.html?com/firebase/ui/FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.html) class instead of [FirebaseRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) which accepts only FirebaseRecyclerOptions as parameter in constructor

Comment: Clean you project once and try. And also what is the error you are getting now

Comment: can you tell how exactly can we use FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter?

Comment: I have already link mentioned in the above answer https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/index.html?com/firebase/ui/FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.html